# GStreamer: Eliminating sped-up playback after connection loss

Tags: raspberry-pi, streaming, gstreamer

I’m working on a team that’s using GStreamer through Raspivid on a Raspberry Pi to get FPV footage streaming from a camera on a drone for animal research.  When doing range tests, we’ve found that when losing the stream, it freezes, and when the stream is back, it goes through the downtime sped up until it catches up to real time. How do we turn this off so that we see real time as soon as we get the stream back?

The command run on the Pi:

```
raspivid -t 0 -h 730 -w 1296 -fps 25 -b 2000000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse !  rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=YOUR-PI-IP-ADDRESS port=5000
```

The command run on the base computer:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=192.168.1.11 port=5000  ! gdpdepay !  rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

(from [this tutorial](http://pi.gbaman.info/?p=150))

Answer (score 0):

Not easy to tell. It depends what you want - and how to archive that. Your protocols chosen basically ensure that no data is lost. But obviously this results in your described behavior. Perhaps you want dropping data on the PI. See `gst-inspect-1.0 tcpserversink` for options of buffers here (`buffers-max` for example). Note however this probably results in a broken bit stream. That will lead to a distorted image on the receiver until an key frame has arrived again (encoder settings define this setting, in your case it may be something in the camera).